# Problem while trying to ftp file > 2GB using ftplib

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, aws-glue, ftplib

I have an AWS Glue job in Python2.7 that is trying to ftp files from my s3 bucket to a client server. I am using pythons inbuilt ftplib library to do so. I am able to ftp the files as long as the file is less than 2GB. The moment the file size goes above 2GB it fails with the following error

cat: precise-error-tmp-file.txt: No such file or directory

I have tried altering the block size but it doesnt help

```
def upload_from_s3_ftplib(s3_bucket, s3_file, ftp_host, ftp_username, 
                          ftp_password, ftp_directory):
"""Uploads the given file at the given S3 URL to the given FTP server 
    using the ftplib library"""

file_name = ntpath.basename(s3_file)
logger.info(" file name {}".format(file_name))

ftp = FTP(ftp_host)
logger.info("Connected")
ftp.login(user=ftp_username, passwd=ftp_password)
logger.info("Login Successful")

if ftp_directory.strip() <> '':
    ftp.cwd(ftp_directory)
    logger.info('Working directory changed to {}'.format(ftp_directory))
logger.info("Transfer file remote FTP {}".format(ftp_directory + "/" + s3_file))

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(s3_bucket, s3_file)
body = obj.get()['Body'].read()

ftp.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(file_name), BytesIO(body))
logger.info('File transmitted!!!')
ftp.quit()
```